# Как получить значение SQLSTATE в обработчике EXCEPTION?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[В этой главе документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-Compliance-To-Core-SQL2011.html) говорится, что Oracle полностью поддерживает `E171, SQLSTATE`.

В PostgreSQL можно прочитать стандартный код ошибки через переменную `SQLSTATE` (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3952b0b8bdfef01450caa097ade6c822)):

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    v_1 int;
BEGIN
    v_1 := 1/0;
EXCEPTION WHEN DIVISION_BY_ZERO THEN 
    RAISE EXCEPTION '<%> - % ', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;
END;
$$
```

Но в Oracle (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eed7d83fe1bad6a1ada29ed923b656f8)) эта переменная не известна:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(1/0);
EXCEPTION WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: '||SQLSTATE||' - '||SQLERRM);
END;
/
ORA-06550: line 4, column 59:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SQLSTATE' must be declared
```

`SQLCODE`, который объявлен устаревшим в SQL-92, работает в Oracle:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(1/0);
EXCEPTION WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: '||SQLCODE||' - '||SQLERRM);
END;
/
dbms_output: Error: -1476 - ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
```

Как получить `SQLSTATE` в Oracle?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Can I get SQLSTATE value in an EXCEPTION handler in Oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65291605) от участника [@iwis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4592248/iwis)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65291605

Answer (score 3):

Документация на самом деле не очень понятна, но [верху по ссылке](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-Compliance-To-Core-SQL2011.html), написано:

> - Oracle Database server, release 12.2
> - OTT (Oracle Type Translator), release 12.2
> - Pro*C/C++, release 12.2
> - Pro*COBOL, release 12.2

Первый пункт означает, что БД Oracle поддерживает `SQLSTATE`, а остальные 3-и пункта являются клиентами SQL. В вопросе используете клиент PL/SQL, которого нет в списке. К сожалению, распространенные SQL-клиенты Oracle, такие как PL/SQL, SQL*Plus и SQLcl, похоже, не поддерживают переменную `SQLSTATE`. Однако, драйверы для других языков, например: JDBC, ODBC, включают ее.

Если действительно нужны коды `SQLSTATE` в PL/SQL, то рекомендуемым решением будет, написать функцию мапирования `SQLCODE` и `SQLSTATE`, например, [на основе этой таблицы](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpcc/handling-run-time-errors.html).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65292034) от участника [kfinity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3061852/kfinity)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Через JDBC соединение можно получить `SQLSTATE` [методом `getSQLState`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getSQLState()) класса `SQLException`.

Исходник Java калсса:

```java
create or replace and compile java source named testsqlstate AS
import java.sql.*;

public class TestSQLState
{
    public static String exec (String qry) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:default:connection:");
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement (qry);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return e.getSQLState();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
/
```

Его надо обернуть в PL/SQL функцию:

```
create or replace function getsqlstate (qry varchar2) return varchar2
as language java name 'TestSQLState.exec (java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
/
```

Вызов и результат:

```sql
exec dbms_output.put_line ('result='||getsqlstate ('select 1/0 from dual'));
```

> result=22012

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65291994) от участника [MT0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509264/mt0)</sub>